# Entity Framework keeps asking Credentials

Tags: c#, visual-studio, entity-framework

Since a recent Visual Studio update, my Entity Framework seems to be broken. Previously, I could enter my credentials once when adding my Database Model, and then update the database by simply opening the database model from my solution and right-clicking on any white space, and clicking on “Update model from database”. However, now every time I do that, the connection window opens and I have to re-enter my credentials. I’ve tried deleting the model completely and re-adding the database from scratch, but this does not resolve the issue. I have also confirmed that the Web.Config file does have the correct credentials.

Is anyone else experiencing this issue? I can't find anything on Google.

Comment: Have you tried to connect via a connection string?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-7.0/breaking-changes#encrypt-true

Comment: @LorenzoCacciola, How would you connect using a Connection String?

Comment: @GertArnold, we are using Entity Framework 6.

Answer (score 0):

inside the onconfiguring method of the context Connect to the database via the connection string

```
        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder options)
        {
        options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("ConnectionString"));
        }
```

in this code i take the connection string from the appsetting.json but you can write directly the string in the method (not the best practice)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to link the database with a string follow these steps:

1. Find App.config and add it under

   ```
    <connectionStrings>
    <add name=" what you want to fill " connectionString="server= your server name;database= your database name;uid= account;pwd= password " providerName="System.Data.Sqlclient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
   ```

As shown below:

[image]

2. Registration context

Create a Context.cs file for basic configuration of the database.

After configuration, the database can be accessed based on foreign keys and primary keys. At the same time, this container is also a necessary class of the data access layer, and subsequent operations rely on it. In order to realize one-to-many and many-to-many relationships, use the OnModelCreating method.

Next, we register the context, realize the link of the data, and use DbSet.
Here is a simple example:

```
public class StudentContext : DbContext
    {
        public StudentContext() : base("con")
        {
            Database.SetInitializer<StudentContext>(null);
        }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<OneToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
            modelBuilder.Conventions.Remove<ManyToManyCascadeDeleteConvention>();
        }
        public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Class> Class { get; set; }
        public DbSet<College> College { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Course> Course { get; set; }
    }
```